# S3 put objects tag bulk, but not overwrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In s3, I have 100 objects. 50 of them have an existing tag value, other 50 no tags at all. I want to apply the tag value in bulk to those objects (50) which doesn't have any tag values & shouldn't overwrite the tag value for the other 50 objects. How can I achieve it? I need to apply this solution for millions of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.
- Write a script to filter-out rows where the tag already exists, leaving only a list of objects that do *not* have the tag
- Use [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html) to set the tag on those remaining objects

This is highly scalable.

Comment: Thanks John, can you please help me with the sample script? I explored the APIs & even spoke with the AWS support. They don't have any APIs to filter out based on the tags. They recommend to get the tag values for all the objects & then filter it out & then apply the batch operations.

Comment: That is correct. Amazon S3 Inventory supplies a CSV file. You can then write a program in your favourite programming language that can process that file to your requirements (this process does not use any AWS services or APIs). Then, use the output of that script as an input to S3 Batch operations.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It appears that the specific case would require doing API calls. S3 Inventory does not include user supplied tags in the CSV report and there is no way to add them out of the box as of now.